# Binary tree search doesn't work

Tags: c++

```
template<class T>
class Tree {
  public:
    Tree(TreeNode *rootPtr = NULL)
    {
        this->rootPtr = rootPtr;
    };
    TreeNode<T> *search(string x);
    bool insert(T x);
    TreeNode * remove(T x);
    TreeNode *getRoot(){ return rootPtr; };
    Tree getLeftSubtree(); Tree getRightSubtree();
    bool isEmpty(){ return rootPtr == NULL; };

private:
    TreeNode<T> *rootPtr;
};
```

I get this error

```
C2955: 'TreeNode' : use of class template requires template argument list
```

---

The `TreeNode` class is:

```
template <class T>
class TreeNode{
    T data; // different data type for other apps
    TreeNode<T> *left; // a pointer to left child
    TreeNode<T> *right; // a pointer to right child
  public:
    TreeNode(T x = 0, TreeNode *left = NULL,TreeNode *right = NULL)
    {
        data = x;
        this->left = left;
        this->right = right;
    };
    T getData() { return data; };
    TreeNode<T> *getLeft() { return left; };
    TreeNode<T> *getRight() { return right; };
    void setData(T x) { data = x; };
    void setLeft(TreeNode *ptr) { left = ptr; };
    void setRight(TreeNode *ptr) { right = ptr; };
    template<class T> friend class Tree;
};
```

Comment: You need to make sure you template everything that should be templated - for exampled, the return type of `getRoot()` should be `TreeNode<T>*` not `TreeNode*`.  Likewise the return type of `getLeftSubtree` should be `Tree<T>`(`*`).  It would help if you improved your formatting though, and included the declaration of your `TreeNode` class/struct

Comment: Where are you implementing your methods. If they are outside the class it won't work because it is a template class. Template class methods must be inline with the class itself

Comment: @Chemicalk1d *"If they are outside the class it won't work / Template class methods must be inline with the class itself"* - that's just not true, though it is substantially easier for a beginner to get the notation right.  To define outside the class, it'd be e.g. `template <class T> TreeNode<T>* Tree<T>::remove(T x) { ... }`.

Answer (score 0):

I appended the code for the `TreeNode` class posted here into the question - TonyD

Comment: This should be moved to your question.  Edit your question and paste this text.